# Most visited pages in SharePoint site 2010 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

How can I find most visited pages in SharePoint 2010 site using JavaScript.

Comment: What have you tried already? Can you provide some code? Please share some more details.

Comment: I have implemented this functionality by using SharePoint. But i want this functionality by using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

There is somethign called as Google Analytics API which will get connected to the sharepoint site and will retrive the number of hits - i dont think it is possible to extract those using pure JS/Javascript

Regards
Arjun